# tix ComboBox issue with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, tix

Using the following Python 3 code :

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import tix

class App(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        cmbbx = tix.ComboBox()
        cmbbx.pack()
        self.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = App()
```

I'm trying to create a simple window containing an empty combobox.
When I run the program with the `python3` command, I get the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combo.py", line 12, in <module>
    application = App()
  File "combo.py", line 7, in __init__
    cmbbx = tix.ComboBox()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/tix.py", line 583, in __init__
    cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/tix.py", line 315, in __init__
    self.tk.call(widgetName, self._w, *extra)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "tixComboBox"
```

After some searches, I find that I need to replace each `tkinter` with `tix` in my code to make it work, but this gives me another error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combo.py", line 12, in <module>
    application = App()
  File "combo.py", line 6, in __init__
    tix.Tk.__init__(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/tix.py", line 218, in __init__
    self.tk.eval('package require Tix')
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package Tix
```

[Another link](https://bugs.python.org/issue6309) showed that I must use `root.tk.eval('package require Tix')`, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm a bit lost between all those `tkinter` and `tix`, and I think that the previous solutions only work with Python 2, as it talks about `Tix` and not `tix`.

Do you have any idea to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html) states that `tix` is deprecated in Python 3 and that `ttk` must be used.
My new code is :

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        cmbbx = tkinter.ttk.Combobox()
        cmbbx.pack()
        self.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = App()
```